# Using count aggregate based on the current row on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL server and trying to get the the course code , title and the number of students who may take **that course** ( current course) , Knowing that for a student to take the course, he should pay at least half the course price , below are the tables :

[image: courses table]

[image: students table]

[image: studentCourses table]

I tried the folowing code , and faced the issue of "Column 'courseStudent.paid' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"
here is the sql code I used :

```
select courses.code, courses.title , courses.courseId ,
 (select  count(*) from courseStudent inner join courses on courseStudent.courseId = courses.courseId
  group by courseStudent.courseId having  courseStudent.paid>courses.price/2)
from courses ;
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Images of data don't help us help you. Expected results do help.

Comment: What do you not understand about the error? You can't put a non-aggregated column in `HAVING` nor does it make sense to do so

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT  c.courseId,c.code,c.title, COUNT(1) AS NoOfStudentEnrolled FROM courseStudent cs 
 JOIN courses c ON cs.courseId = c.courseId
 WHERE cs.paid>c.price/2
GROUP BY c.courseId,c.code,c.title
```